# Can I use Kibana to visualize log file without elastic search?

Tags: kibana, logfile

I am some log data stored in log files. I cannot export it to elastic search. Is there a way I can directly use these log files to visualise graphs in Kibana?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

> [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/introduction.html) is an open source analytics and visualization platform designed
>   to work with Elasticsearch. You use Kibana to search, view, and
>   interact with data stored in Elasticsearch indices.

Instead of Kibana use any of these: [How do you visualize logfiles in realtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94592/how-do-you-visualize-logfiles-in-realtime)

Comment: so is there a way to export existing log file to elastic search?

Comment: Yes. You can use `logstash` to export existing log file to `elasticsearch`.